# Projecting 3D Data set to 2D plane using pfgplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, 3d, pgfplots

I would like to project a 3D data set into a 2D plane at the bottom of a predefined 3D axis enviroment. Therefore I use the following code. The code does not achieve the wished results and plots a surface. Sadly, I am not as experienced as I would like to be when it come to tikz and pfgplots.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={135}{45},
    width=0.65\textwidth,
    height=0.65\textwidth,
    xlabel={Length (mm)},
    ylabel={Width (mm)},
    zlabel={Phase (rad)},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=45,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=45,
    zmin=-0.5,
    zmax=0.7,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    zmajorgrids
    ]
    
      \addplot3 [surf,z buffer=sort,
mesh/rows=41,
mesh/ordering=colwise,
point meta=rawz, 
z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{2.5}}] file{Folder/Subfolder/SurfData.dat};  
 

   
       
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
```

As a first step, the image should be projected at the bottom of the 3D enviroment at the lowest z axis point equal zmin=-0.5.

[image]

My question is closed related to the following link.
[Smooth projection of a surf plot - tikz/gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476458/smooth-projection-of-a-surf-plot-tikz-gnuplot?rq=1)

In contrast, I have a 3D data set an not an explicit mathematical expression.

EDIT:

I think I am almost there, but my "flat" surface plot does not have any color:
I generated the test data in MatLab using:

```
a=peaks(41);
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:41,1:41);
data = [ x(:) y(:) a(:) ];
save Test.dat data -ASCII
```

Followed by the Latex Script

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
 
    \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={135}{45},colormap/viridis,
width=0.65\textwidth,
height=0.65\textwidth,
xlabel={Length (mm)},
ylabel={Width (mm)},
zlabel={Phase (rad)},
xmin=0,
xmax=45,
ymin=0,
ymax=45,
zmin=-8,
zmax=8,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids
]

  
\addplot3 [surf,z buffer=sort,mesh/rows=41,mesh/ordering=colwise] table[z expr=-5]{Test.dat};  

   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe a visual of what you're willing to achieve could help?

Comment: I think my question is close related to the following link. In my case I would like to project a surface plot to the bottom . In contrast, I dont have a math Expression, I have a data set given as .dat. My first idea was to make a png out of the data set and projecting it to the bottom. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476458/smooth-projection-of-a-surf-plot-tikz-gnuplot?rq=1